# Comparing arrays with meta_query in pre_get_posts

Tags: advanced-custom-fields, meta-query, pre-get-posts

I'm working on a form for filtering a list of posts using custom fields created with the Advanced Custom Fields plugin. Because of the form, I'm using the `pre_get_posts` action to change the query via GET requests. (following code references are either PHP or dumped from `print_r()`)

I set the meta_query like this:

```
$query->set('meta_query',$filter);
```

and `$filter` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [key] => delivery_method
            [value] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Online
                    [1] => Scheduled

                )

            [compare] => IN
        )
)
```

The custom field that I am querying is structured like this:

```
Array (
    [delivery_method] => Array (
        [0] => Online
        [1] => Scheduled
    )
)
```

When I look for posts with `[compare] => IN` (as above), no posts are returned. When I look for posts with `[compare] => NOT IN`, all of the posts are returned.

I am trying to return only those posts which have a specific "delivery method". Is there a way to compare the two arrays that I missed? or do I have to somehow explode one of the arrays and compare individual values against an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ACF Documentation recommends checking the values individually rather than simultaneously using an array.

The following code is from the ACF Documentation for the Checkbox field type:

http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/field-types/checkbox/

```
/*
*  Query posts for a checkbox value.
*  This method uses the meta_query LIKE to match the string "red" to the database value a:2:{i:0;s:3:"red";i:1;s:4:"blue";} (serialized array)
*  The above value suggests that the user selected "red" and "blue" from the checkbox choices
*/

$posts = get_posts(array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'field_name', // name of custom field
            'value' => '"red"', // matches exaclty "red", not just red. This prevents a match for "acquired"
            'compare' => 'LIKE'
        )
    )
));
```

Therefore the query in `pre_get_posts` should look like this:

```
$filter = array(
    array(
        'key' => 'delivery_method'
        'value' => '"Online"'
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    ),
    array(
        'key' => 'delivery_method'
        'value' => '"Scheduled"'
        'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
)

$query->set('meta_query',$filter);
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am correct, you have a field that contain an array, to be clear, something that you can save using:

```
add_post_meta( $postid, 'delivery_method', array('Online', 'Scheduled') );
```

Then you want to query posts where field 'delivery_method' = `array( 'Online', 'Scheduled')`.

The problem is that a meta query like the yours:

```
$meta_query = array(
  array(
    'key' => 'delivery_method',
    'value' => array( 'Online', 'Scheduled' ),
    'compare' => 'IN'
  )
);
```

returns posts having the 'deliver_method' key set to *'Online'* (string) or *'Scheduled'* (string) or both, but your post has the key 'deliver_method' saved as array, so its value is [serialized](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) by WordPress before being saved in database, and you can't query for a serialized value using an unserialized array...

So, if you want to store different delivery methods, it's fairly better if you use multiple values for same key, instead of a key with multiple values, e.g.

```
add_post_meta( $postid, 'delivery_method', 'Online' );
add_post_meta( $postid, 'delivery_method', 'Scheduled' );
```

In this way, using proper args, you'll be able to get posts having one of the methods, or both, depending on your needs.

I sincerly don't know how to implement this using ACF, and however the plugin-specific way is off topic for this site, but I think the concept is simple and you can simply apply on that plugin.

A dirty hack for the specific case is query using as value the serialized value

```
$meta_query = array(
  array(
    'key' => 'delivery_method',
    'value' => serialize ( array( 'Online', 'Scheduled' ) )
  )
);
```

This meta query returns the posts having both methods saved as array.

Comment: This would work, but I realized that it would pull only those posts with both "Online" and "Scheduled". It would not pull those with either "Online" or "Scheduled".